# laravel Yajra can't connect to oracle

Tags: php, laravel, oracle, iis

Hi everyone First thanks for your reading

My webside is using IIS by window server 2016、PHP 8.0 and laravel 9

When i use Yajra, I got the error message like
" Undefined constant "Yajra\Pdo\OCI_DEFAULT" "

I have already uncomment php.ini for oci8

[image]

thans for your reading

Comment: Please make sure that oci8 extension is installed correctly. Try running php -m | grep oci8 and phpinfo in the browser to see if the extension is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the proper Oracle Instant Client for your PHP version, to your environment path variable.

[Documentation](https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html).

Comment: i have already set the path, it still not work and show the same error

Comment: btw my oracle is 10g

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error after upgrading Laravel and OCI8 from ^8 to ^10 but I believe the issue was introduced in Laravel ^9 yajra/laravel-oci8:^9

1. Check the Oci8 extension is installed on your system by running the following command in your terminal:

   php -m | grep oci8

If the output shows "oci8" then the extension is successfully installed.

2. If you don't see any output, it means the extension is not installed. (To Install OCI8 https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php NOTE: To install OCI8 you will have first needed to have installed Oracle Instant Client https://gist.github.com/nasrulhazim/308c9f59a2ddba364b4b908ee9238265)

   pecl install oci8
3. Once the extension is installed, you need to enable it in your PHP configuration. Pecl install should do this automatically but if not then locate your php.ini file (usually located in /etc/php//apache2/php.ini or /etc/php//cli/php.ini) and add the following line

   extension=oci8
4. Make sure to restart your Apache or PHP-FPM service, I use Laravel valet so

   valet restart

**5) Finally, clear the Laravel cache by running the following command (this was my issue!)**

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

**After running the cache:clear command it worked (well almost..), or at least it gave a different error.**

```
oci_connect(): Invalid character set name: utf8mb4
```

This one was much easier to resolve by just changing the character set in the config/database.php file

```
'oracle' => [
...
'charset'        => 'AL32UTF8',
'prefix'         => '',
```

],

Note that the charset value is set to AL32UTF8, which is the recommended character set for Oracle databases. Also, make sure that the prefix value is set to an empty string (''), as this will disable table prefixing.The utf8mb4 character set is commonly used in MySQL databases to support a wider range of characters, including emojis. However, Oracle databases do not support utf8mb4 directly, as it is a MySQL-specific character set. In the previous version of Laravel or the Oci8 package they had a different default character set that was compatible with Oracle databases.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is an old one but I chip in anyway.

The issue is not installed oci8 extension as stated in other solutions but what people seem to forget is that if you are on a production server then it depends where do you execute your oracle connection (command line or FPM).

CLI - you can easily check with `php -m | grep oci8` if it is installed and if not follow one of many tutorials. If you are using Laravel Forge you can edit PHP configuration in your server settings of PHP.

FPM - I do not know how to check if extension is loaded with FPM but I know that it has a separate config in Laravel Forge in PHP settings and if you do not add oci8 extension to that file the exact error will come up.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

if you used nginx with installed php-fpm service, try restart this service.

In my case, CentOS
`sudo systemctl start php-fpm`

Works for me!

Good look!

Answer (score -1):

The error message you're seeing is because the constant "Yajra\Pdo\OCI_DEFAULT" is not defined in your code. This constant is used in the Yajra\Pdo\Oci8 package to set the default connection mode.

To resolve this issue, you can define the constant in your code. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
php
<?php
define('Yajra\Pdo\OCI_DEFAULT', 0);
// Your code here
```

Alternatively, you can define the constant in your .env file if you're using Laravel. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
YAJRA_PDO_OCI_DEFAULT=0
```

After defining the constant, make sure to clear your application's configuration cache by running the following command:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

This should resolve the error message you're seeing. If you're still encountering issues, please ensure that you have the correct version of the Yajra\Pdo\Oci8 package installed in your project. You can check the version by looking in your composer.json file or by running the following command:

```
composer show yajra/pdo-via-oci8
```